# change size of div function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, onclick

I have a function that alters the size of a div when I click on it. Now I have to write the onclick command in my html page, but I want it to stand in the extern .js file.

Now in html:

```
 <div id="box1" class="kaesten" onclick="changeSize('box1')"> Title 1 </div>
```

What I want:

```
<div id="box1" class="kaesten" > Title 1 </div>
```

Tried something in jquery but it didn't work:

```js
function changeSize(id) {
  var elem = document.getElementById(id);
  var currentAbsoluteElem = document.getElementById('dummy');
  var text = elem.innerHTML;
  currentAbsoluteElem.innerHTML = text;
  currentAbsoluteElem.setAttribute('style', 'display:block');
  /*Extra styling neeed  to be done here*/

}

var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('kaesten');
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
  elems[i].onclick = function() {
    changeSize(this.id);
  }
}

var absoluteCl = document.getElementsByClassName('absoluteclass');
absoluteCl[0].onclick = function() {
  console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('absoluteclass'))
  document.getElementsByClassName('absoluteclass')[0].setAttribute('style', 'display:none');
}
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.kaesten').click(function() {
    changeSize($(this).attr('id'));
});
});
```

```css
.kaesten {
  width: 240px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: darkgrey;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #000;
  border: 5px solid #F0F8ff;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #777;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.absoluteclass {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: darkgrey;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  left: calc(30%);
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="box1" class="kaesten">title1</div>
<div id="box2" class="kaesten">title2</div>
<div id="box3" class="kaesten">title3</div>
<div id="box4" class="kaesten">title4</div>
<div id="dummy" class="absoluteclass"></div>
```

I know it works in the fiddle, but I don't know why it doesn't work on my homepage without writing the function in the div's.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is that you are trying to assign the onclick event handler before the DOM is actually rendered and ready. My suggestion is to wrap your "initialization code" inside a $(document).ready() method. As follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Apply the on click event handlers here, using jQuery or not
    // For instance:
    $('.kaesten').click(function() {
        changeSize($(this).attr('id'));
    });
});
```

Comment: That's what I wanted, but it doesn't work it only works when I put  the onclick="changeSize('box1')" command in each div tag!

Comment: @nolags I understand. Have you already applied the $(document).ready() method like I suggested? The thing is, if your code is triggered before document (DOM) is ready, the event handlers won't be applied - simply because the elements which should listen on the click event are not yet created at the time you try to apply the event handlers. That is why you need to use the $(document).ready() method which ensure your code is executed only after the DOM was prepared. Only once the DOM is ready you can play with it (i.e. apply event handlers etc.).

Comment: Yes I did. I wrote it under the JavaScript function in the extern file but still I can't open the big div by onclick.

Comment: Could you please post the updated files? Also one hint. The JS files may be cached by your browser. Check with the Developer Tool in the browser if the script used by the browser is up to date.

Comment: Posted it! Sorry but where does that stand in the developer tool?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to pass the id from jquery to your function you should do it like this:

```
$(function(){
    $(".kaesten").click(function(){
        changeSize($(this).attr("id"));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use .css in jquery

```
$(function(){
            $(".kaesten").click(function(){
                $(this).css({'width' : '600px' , 'height' : '600px'});;
            });
        });
```

Comment: That's not what I supposed to do. I want the function only to stand in an extern javascript file, so I can delete the onclick="changeSize('box1')" command in each div tag!